# Android Studio : How to change default cursor style and behavior?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

In Eclipse and many other editors we've same behavior for these [**Cursor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28computing%29) styles:

[image: Default Cursor in Eclipse]  **Insert** mode: The cursor inserts a character at its current position, forcing all characters past it one position further.

[image: Insert Cursor in Eclipse]  **Overtype** mode : The cursor, when typing, overwrites any text that is present in the current location.

But In **Android Studio**, this cursor is behaving **opposite**

[image]

[image]

This is very annoying for me, Can anyone tell me how to fix this behavior ?

(As we know in windows, We can toggle cursor behavior & style by pressing **[Insert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key)** key )

Comment: My Android Studio works fine in fact.

Comment: @SilentKnight Then I think, you've correct settings in your editor.

Comment: No, it's default setting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At last I found solution of my problem :)

So, following is the fix for it:

`File - > Settings -> Editor (IDE Settings) -> Appearance->` Then uncheck `Use Block caret`

[image: Use block Caret]

Comment: Thank you. It's been a pet peeve o mine. I wonder why they "created" a brand-new feature and even set it as default.

Comment: On my AS it wasn't default but the problem just appeared randomly while using the IDE. Changing the setting solved the problem.

Answer (score 11):

press the insert button once. It will be fine for every type of programming editors like Android Studio, Dev C++ etc.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to do this
1. The first is to go through the settings to change it
That is, File >> Settings >> Editor >> Appearance >> Use block caret ( should be unchecked )

2. On Windows press the fn + ins

Comment: Just to point out for Linux users atleast, fn + ins is shutdown, which as I just found out is a little annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the answers there is another case which could lead to this situation. I accidently installed IdeaVIM plugin to my IDE, and that caused it to have cursor in overtype mode. Disabling that plugin solved my problem.

To disable a plugin go to `File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Installed` and then uncheck the plugin you want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing helped, then you can try this scheme: Tools -> Vim Emulator (disable the check mark)

Answer (score 0):

Restart Android studio it should work

```
1 >> File
2 >> Exit 
3 >> Launch Android studio
```

It should work