# How to change default cursor style in Android Studio using windows 11?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, windows-11

### Problem Description

I updated my windows to **windows 11** and when i installed android studio again i started to face problems related to the mouse cursor.
It always looks like this when I open a new file through android studio:

[image: windows_11_resulted_cursor]

I would like the cursor to look like this:

[image: windows_11_expected_cursor]

But for this to be possible I currently have to keep pressing the "insert" key on the keyboard every time I go to a new file, and that's pretty annoying.

### My failed attempt

As described in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29842115/11111289) I did the following that is in the image below:

[image]

But it didn't work. **I suspect it's something exclusive to windows 11**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to windows 11 as I suspected, but rather to the Vim plugin available for the IDE. To solve this, just disable the plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the 'Insert' key on your keyboard. That should fix your problem.